Row wise statistical mode in table function
I have a table in SQL Server called SurveyData found here
That looks like this:
-- Create the table
CREATE TABLE SurveyData 
(
    country VARCHAR(50),
    year INT,
    val1 INT,
    val2 INT,
    val3 INT
);

-- Insert 10 rows of data
INSERT INTO SurveyData (country, year, val1, val2, val3) 
VALUES ('USA', 2020, 4, 4, 5),
       ('Canada', 2021, 2, 4, 3),
       ('Germany', 2022, 5, 5, 4),
       ('France', 2020, 3, 4, 2),
       ('UK', 2021, 4, 2, 3),
       ('Australia', 2022, 3, 3, 4),
       ('Italy', 2020, 5, 5, 5),
       ('Spain', 2021, 1, 2, 3),
       ('Mexico', 2022, 4, 4, 4),
       ('Brazil', 2020, 2, 3, 1);

-- Add the mode column to the table
SELECT * FROM SurveyData

I want to create a table function that will take two parameters declared country =USA and year =2021 and the output will be the filtered table df by country USA and year 2021 and the third column will be the statistical mode (most frequent) of columns val1, val2 and val3 but row wise. How can I do it in SQL Server?

This sounds just more like a basic select statement you could put into a Stored Procedure or a view.  Dont see a need for table function?

@Brad why stored ? also how you can calculate the row wise mode in sql server ?

Please provide a [mre] i.e. show the desired results for a given input

@DaleK mode is the most frequent value that occur row wise not column wise. You can read what it is here .Also column wise mode in sql server is calculated like this.But I think my example is very good.And reproducible.

@HomerJaySimpson without expected output it's hard to know what you want, and noone wants to click on random links from internet stranger, unless they lead to cute puppies

See example
-- parameters
declare @Country varchar(50)= 'USA', @Year int= 2020;

select *
from df
cross apply( select top 1 val,count(*) cnt from ( values (val1),(val2),(val3))t(val)
             group by val
             order by count(*) desc
          )a
where country=@country and year=@year




country
year
val1
val2
val3
val
cnt




USA
2020
4
4
5
4
2



fiddle

Great answer. When there are ties you need to think about what result you want. If the values are interpolable then it might make sense to do an average over them perhaps SELECT AVG(val) FROM (SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES val, COUNT(*) FROM ...... ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) v or some other interpolation.
